# External hardware triggering of a USB3.0 camera with DirectShow and Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, triggers, camera, event-handling, directshow

Using external hardware triggering of a UVC compliant USB3.0 camera, I want to acquire still images utilizing Directshow in our Visual C++ code. Using an API supplied by the camera manufacturer  we can  set the camera in External Trigger Mode . With the camera in Master Mode (“Free Running Mode” with no external triggering) we get the proper event notification code in our DirectShow VC++ program. However, we don’t get the proper event notification code when triggering the camera externally in External Trigger Mode, as described below.

To get the event notification code of the event interface IMediaEventEx *pEvent of the running filter graph we call

```
hr = pEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);
```

or

```
while (hr = pEvent->GetEvent(&evCode, &param1, &param2, 0), SUCCEEDED(hr))
  {
    hr = pEvent->FreeEventParams(evCode, param1, param2);

    if ((evCode == EC_COMPLETE))
    {   
    break;
    }
  }
```

In Master Mode (no external trigger) we obtain the event notification code EC_COMPLETE for evCode (i.e. all data has been rendered) and to grab the image data from the camera we can call

```
hr = pSGrabber->GetCurrentBuffer(&cbBufSize, NULL);
```

and

```
hr = pSGrabber->GetCurrentBuffer(&cbBufSize, (long*)pBuffer);
```

Here pSGrabber is the ISampleGrabber interface for the Sample Grabber Filter.
However, in External Trigger Mode for evCode we only get the event notification code EC_ACTIVATE and therefore we cannot grab any image data.  It can also be noted that via the IAMVideoControl interface for the still Pin we set the flag for external trigger

```
hr = pAMVidControl->SetMode(pPinStill, VideoControlFlag_ExternalTriggerEnable);
```

where IPin *pPinStill is the pointer to the still Pin.

We know that the external trigger pulses we use are adequate for triggering the camera, because with a commercial piece of software we succeed with triggering the camera externally. Therefore, I believe the problem is related to DirectShow programming. Does anyone have experience with grabbing image data in DirectShow when using external triggering of a camera? Or point to some source of information?

Thank you very much.